# Calling fortran function of lapack library from CUDA C

Tags: c, cuda, fortran, lapack

I am calling a fortran function sgesv() of lapack library for solving linear equations for unknown vector from my CUDA C routine. As per the general rule I am declaring the function as sgesv_() and invoking it in the main() function passing the variables by reference. I am following the commands to compile and execute as:

```
nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -c test_CCUDA3.cu
gfortran -Wno-main -fno-second-underscore -fPIE -L"/usr/local/lib" -llapack test_CCUDA3.o -L"/usr/local/cuda/lib64" -I /usr/local/include -lcudart -lcuda -lstdc++ -lcublas
./a.out
```

There is no compilation error. However, while linking the object files I get the following error even though I recomplied with -fPIE:

```
/usr/bin/ld: test_CCUDA3.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Declaration and Invoking the function is as follows:

```
extern void sgesv_(int, int, float (*)[2], int, float [], float [2], int, int *);
//    sgesv(2, 1, aa, 2, pivot, &bb, 2, &rc);

int main()
{
................
................
    float aa[2][2],bb[2],pivot[2];
    int rc;
...........
...........
        aa[0][0]=3.;
        aa[1][0]=1.;
        aa[0][1]=.6667;
        aa[1][1]=.3333;
        
        bb[0]=5.;
        bb[1]=6.;
sgesv_(2, 1, aa, 2, pivot, bb, 2, &rc);
.................
.................
}
```

Any help on executing the code will be much appreciated. Fairly a beginner in CUDA. I am calling this fortran library function in the main() not in the device code.

Please note:
I tested the compilation and running the code on normal C rather than with CUDA C. It gave me no error and execution gave me accurate solution.

Comment: What about recompiling the CUDA code with `-fPIE` as the compiler say? Try: `nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -c test_CCUDA3.cu -fPIE`

Comment: I did recompiled with -fPIE the error remains the same. However, when I compiled with -no-pie gives :   `undefined reference to sgesv_(int, int, float (*) [2], int, float*, float*, int, int*) 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ` . I am not quiet sure what does -fPIC and -fPIE truly mean. I tried to search but with no luck of really understanding it is doing.

Comment: That is NOT compiling. That is linking. Do you know the difference?

Comment: The compilation line is "nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -c test_CCUDA3.cu". Have you tried adding -fPIE to that and then linking as above?

Comment: @IanBush I do not have a separate *.f90 function file to compile. I directly need to link the library for sgesv_(). Yes, I have tried adding -fPIE to before linking. It throws the following error: ``` nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'fPIE' ```

Comment: Last try. Have you attempted "nvcc -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -fPIE -c test_CCUDA3.cu" and then relinked? It is not clear from the above. IFF that doesn't work we'll think about the (what might be) fortran.

Comment: @IanBush I did try again. Throws nvcc fatal error unknown -fPIE.

Comment: OK, how about as @VladimirF suggests, changing the link line appropriately?

Comment: @VladimirF with nvcc -fPIC, fatal unknown option -fPIC.

Comment: See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=861878  note `--compiler-options -fpie `

Comment: The function you're calling is exposed via a library that has a C interface.  However `nvcc` is a C++ compiler.  You're going to need `extern "C" ...`  not just `extern ...`.  When I make that change, your code compiles/links clean for me with CUDA 11.1 and gfortran 7.5.  So, as indicated in the answer, it may be important to know which versions of CUDA and gfortran you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might have hit this issue [#861878
nvidia-cuda-toolkit: nvcc needs to pass -fpie to compiler](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=861878).

The proposed solution is to use `nvcc --compiler-options -fpie` but see also the respones and other points. It is important to consider your versions of CUDA and GCC.

Comment: But I still do not know what is exactly -fpie or -fpic doing?

Comment: @ambika29 It instruct the compiler to create [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things/findings:
`nvcc --compiler-options -fpie` is the right syntax and it did resolve the issue. @VladimirF thank you for providing that answer for me.

extern "C" ... declaration also required for compiling and executing for as *.cu. However, declaration is not needed at all rather it is redundant  for compiling and executing *.c with **linking to fortran library with C interface**. @RobertCrovella thanks for your input.

The above steps resolved my this particular issue.